# Need to flag names of people in CSV column using Python NLTK

Tags: python, csv, nltk

I have a CSV file structured as such

Record | Description | Date| etc....

1      | Mary Jane does not like the service received. | 07/04/02 |

I need to flag instances where a private names are present in the text field. I want to set up two new columns in the CSV 1 that states a record contains a name, and another that lists the names in the record. It'll allow an expedited cleanup using Google Refine after it's run across 75k records. I know that NLTK can tokenize these, but am relatively new in how to use it to perform such a task.

The output csv file should look like this:

Record | Description | Date| Contains Name | Named Entities

1      | Mary Jane does not like the service received. | 07/04/02 |True | Mary Jane

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with nltk, but http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html seems like it would have what you're looking for.